# Ruby on Rails Tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the below HTML for Tabs using Bootstrap. Now I want to click on particular tab and show data related to that tab. How can I do that

All order

Internet

Telephone

Cellphone

Cable

Bundle

Comment: Can you share what you have done till now? Share your controller code and HTML for these tabs

Comment: I want a solution as how I can connect it to my controller to show the details.

Comment: You can create a listener to make an AJAX request back to your application and post the response in a div of the bootstrap tab.

Comment: As said by @Prity, it would be nice if you post the code you wrote, so that we can help you make this code work : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade active in"> <div class="row desc_heading"> <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-5"> <h5>Description</h5> </div> <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-7"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Status</h5> </div> <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Price</h5> </div> <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Order No.</h5> </div> <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Order Total</h5> </div> </div> </div> </div>

Comment: The above is the view in which dynamic data will come from rails controller when I click on the below:- <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" aria-expanded="false">All order</a></li>

Comment: <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" aria-expanded="false">All order</a></li>
        <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" aria-expanded="false">Internet</a></li>
      </ul>

Comment: <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade active in">
          <div class="row desc_heading">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-5"> <h5>Description</h5> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-7">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Status</h5> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Price</h5>   </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Order No.</h5> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Order Total</h5> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

Comment: <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">

          <div class="row desc_heading">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-5"> <h5>Description</h5> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-7">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Status</h5> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Price</h5>   </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Order No.</h5> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Order Total</h5> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

Comment: Now how can I get data from controllers

Answer (score 0):

Link every tab to the controller#action with the category as a parameter.

Ex:
`items_path?category=internet`

In ItemsController#index action, write a query to filter data of required category.

`@items = Item.where(category: params[:category])`

Comment: <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" aria-expanded="false">All order</a></li>

Comment: where should I pass items_path?category=internet

Comment: <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade active in">

          <div class="row desc_heading">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-5"> <h5>Description</h5> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-7">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Status</h5> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Price</h5>   </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Order No.</h5> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"> <h5>Order Total</h5> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

Comment: please paste your code in controller and view files if you have.

Comment: the above code is for view and I am unable to connect to controller

Comment: Can you please provide a proper solution.

Comment: you have to put it in anchor tag href attribute.
Here, I have taken an example so that you can understand. You have to put your routes of your controller. check `rake db:routes` for your app routes.

Comment: In your view file file_name.html.erb,
`<%= link_to 'All Orders', items_path %>
<%= link_to 'Internet', items_path(category: 'internet') %>
<%= link_to 'Telephone', items_path(category: 'telephone') %>
<%= link_to 'Cellphone', items_path(category: 'cellphone') %>
<%= link_to 'Cable', items_path(category: 'cable') %>
<%= link_to 'Bundle', items_path(category: 'bundle') %>`